# How to call an async firebase function from other async function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

Using three functions (getViews, getViewCount and updateCount) I want to **retrieve** a youtube view count and then **store it in a firestore database**. Both functions work *asynchronously*, but when I call getViews() inside updateCount() I get the following error **within updateCount**:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on') which refers to a promise.

Please let me know am I doing wrong here! Code below:

### getViews:

```
exports.getViews = functions
  .runWith({
    secrets: ["YOUTUBE_API"]
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const count = await getViewCount({}); 
    return count;
  });
```

### updateCount:

```
exports.updateCount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const viewData = await this.getViews({ "h": "j" }); //Error occurs here
  const addData = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("viewCount")
    .doc("Count")
    .set(viewData)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
});
```

### getViewCount:

```
const getViewCount = async (arg) => {
  const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: "v3",
    auth: process.env.YOUTUBE_API,
  });

  const count = await youtube.channels.list({
    id: process.env.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID,
    part: "statistics",
  });

  const countData = count.data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
  return countData;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `getViews()` to be a Cloud Function? Would you be calling that from client side or just from `updateCount`? If latter, then just use a normal function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj That's a good question. My goal is to add pub.sub to getViews() and schedule it to run a couple times per day to update the database value, and then grab the value client-side to update a live count on my site. I think getViews() needs to be a cloud function to schedule those calls? I could be wrong tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the code in `getViews()` Cloud Function as well, then it might be better to move that to a different function. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
exports.getViews = functions
  .runWith({
    secrets: ["YOUTUBE_API"]
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const count = await getViewCount({}); // <-- pass required arguments
    return count;
  })
```

```
exports.updateCount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const viewData = await getViewCount({ "h": "j" });
  const addData = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("viewCount")
    .doc("Count")
    .set(viewData)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
});
```

```
// not a Cloud Function
const getViewCount = async (arg) => {
  const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: "v3",
    auth: process.env.YOUTUBE_API,
  });

  const count = await youtube.channels.list({
    id: process.env.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID,
    part: "statistics",
  });

  const countData = count.data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
  return countData;
}
```

Comment: I think this looks cleaner but it still returns a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on') referring to a new promise. Any ideas? I am still learning async await but am not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: @bagel_boy3 can you update your question with your updated complete code? Also, make sure you are not calling any old instances of cloud functions.

Comment: Alrighty I've updated the code, don't believe I'm calling any old instances.

Comment: @bagel_boy3 the `this.getViews` must be `getViewCount` in `updateCount()` function. Please recheck my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for the help! I still have a lot to learn but that helped solve this one